# Having trouble with finding solutions to sine equation.

Tags: trigonometry

The problem is to find solutions to $$\sin(4x -\pi/3) = \sin x$$ over the interval $[0, 2\pi ] $.

I tried expanding out $\sin(4x -\pi/3)$ but the resulting equation turns out to be very complicated. Is there any simpler way to solve this. Somehow [wolfram](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sin(4*x-pi%2F3)+%3D+sin+x) got the exact solutions.

Comment: $x=4x-\frac {\pi}3$ is a possible start.

Comment: Oh my, why didn't i see that. Then I can solve $4x-\frac {\pi}3 = x + 2\pi k $

Comment: Also note that $\sin (\pi-x)=\sin x$

Comment: @MohammadZuhairKhan If i changed the problem to $ \sin(4x -\pi/3) = \cos x$ then we can use the complementary definition of $\sin $ , i.e. $ \cos x = \sin ( \pi/2 - x ) $

Comment: Just to be clear, you are asking that if you are to solve another problem where $\sin (4x-\frac {\pi}3)=\cos x,$ could we use the other identities of $\cos x$? If so, then of course! They are called identities of $\cos x$ because they are always equal, no matter the value of $x$. You could use $\cos x=\sin (\frac {\pi}2 -x)$ or if the question requires it, you could use $\cos x=\sqrt {1-\sin^2 x}$

Comment: Please see my solution below , for original problem, and critique. One moment..

Comment: Sure, whenever you post it.

Comment: Done. Posted below. So we are implicitly using the fact that $ \sin(u) = \sin (v) \implies u = v$.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks for the help (in the comments). 
I will attempt to find the general solution first.

I will use the fact: $$ \sin (u) = \sin(v) \implies u = v $$

Then $$ \sin(4x -\pi/3) = \sin x 
\\ \sin(4x -\pi/3 + 2\pi k_1) = \sin (x+ 2\pi k_2 )~~~\text{where } k_1,k_2 \in \mathbb Z
\\  4x -\pi/3 + 2\pi k_1 =  x+ 2\pi k_2 
\\ 3x -\pi/3 =  2\pi k_2 - 2\pi k_1 
\\ 3x -\pi/3 =  2\pi( k_2 - k_1 )
\\ \qquad \qquad \qquad 3x  =  2\pi( k ) + \pi/3 \quad \text{ where } k = k_2 - k_1\in \mathbb Z 
\\  x = \frac{2\pi  }{3}k + \frac{\pi}{9}$$ And similarly $$\sin(\pi - (4x -\pi/3) ) = \sin x 
\\ \sin(\pi - 4x + \pi/3) ) = \sin x 
\\ \sin( 4/3 \pi - 4x) = \sin x 
\\ \sin( 4/3 \pi - 4x  + 2\pi k_1) = \sin (x+ 2\pi k_2 )
\\  4/3 \pi -4x + 2\pi k_1 =  x+ 2\pi k_2 
\\  5x =  4/3 \pi + 2\pi k_1 - 2\pi k_2 
\\  5x =  4/3 \pi + 2\pi ( k_1 -  k_2 )
\\ \qquad \qquad \qquad 5x  =  4/3 \pi + 2\pi (k) \qquad \text{ where } k = k_2 - k_1 \in \mathbb Z
\\  x = \frac{4\pi}{15} + \frac{2\pi}{5} k$$

Comment: Well done! I liked how you figured out the general equation as well.

Answer (score 0):

$$\sin(4x-\pi/3)=\sin(x)$$
firstly, expand the first term:
$$\sin(4x-\pi/3)=\sin(4x)\cos(\pi/3)-\cos(4x)\sin(\pi/3)=\frac{1}{2}\sin(4x)-\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}\cos(4x)$$
and then you could expand all this out to get a polynomial which may be solved.
Also note that if we restrict the domain of many functions the following is true:

if $f(x)=f(y)$ then $x=y$

there is an answer above which shows how to use this